# Remove all non php data from string

Tags: php, html, string, file, preg-replace

I want to be able to remove all non php data from a string / file.

Now this `preg_replace` line works perfectly:

```
preg_replace('/\?>.*\<?/', '', $src); // Remove all non php data
```

BUT... problem is that it works only for the first match and not for all of the string/file...

Small tweak needed here ;)

Comment: It would be nicer to use the [tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simpler the other way round:

```
preg_match_all('~<\?.+?\?>~s', $src, $m);
$php = implode('', $m[0]);
```

Matching non-php blocks is much trickier, because they can also occur before the first php block and after the last one: `blah <? php ?> blah`.

Also note that no regex solution can handle `<?`'s inside php strings, as in:

```
<? echo "hi ?>";  ?>
```

You have to use [tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) to parse this correctly.

Comment: Great answer ! But still I'm missing something here ? take a look :

<?php

$src = '<?php echo "123";?>  ***remove me*** <?php echo "456"; ?> ***remove me*** <?php echo "789";?>';

$php = preg_match_all('~<\?.+?\?>~s', $src, $m);
$php = implode('', $m[0]);

var_dump ($m);
var_dump ($php);

/* I'm expecting to get : <?php echo "123";?><?php echo "456"; ?><?php echo "789";?> */
?>